# wpf Specify opacity in LiveCharts column

Tags: wpf, livecharts

Is it possible to specify the transparency and make the Y axis line visible in the Column graph?

Here is my source.

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Name="Chart2" Grid.Column="1" DisableAnimations="False" AnimationsSpeed="0" Hoverable="True">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis Labels="51, 52, 62, 71, 72, 81, 82, 101, 102, 4A, 4B, 5A, 5B, ASR, ER" >
            <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                <lvc:Separator Step="1" Stroke="Transparent" />
            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            <lvc:Axis.Sections>
                <lvc:AxisSection Opacity=".2"/>
            </lvc:Axis.Sections>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:Axis MinValue="0" MaxValue="500" Opacity="0.2">
            <lvc:Axis.Sections>
                <lvc:AxisSection Opacity=".2"/>
            </lvc:Axis.Sections>
            <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                <lvc:Separator Step="50" Stroke="Gray"/>
            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Name="Column1" StackMode="Values" Fill="#8b6cc6" MaxColumnWidth="40" Values="10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,50,110,120,130,140,150"></lvc:StackedColumnSeries>
        <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Name="Column2" StackMode="Values" Fill="#ca5982" MaxColumnWidth="40" Values="10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,50,110,120,130,140,150"></lvc:StackedColumnSeries>
        <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Name="Column3" StackMode="Values" Fill="#c3903f" MaxColumnWidth="40" Values="10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,50,110,120,130,140,150"></lvc:StackedColumnSeries>
        <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Name="Column4" StackMode="Values" Fill="#4c9fcb" MaxColumnWidth="40" Values="10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,50,110,120,130,140,150"></lvc:StackedColumnSeries>
        <lvc:StackedColumnSeries Name="Column5" StackMode="Values" Fill="#77d656" MaxColumnWidth="40" Values="10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,50,110,120,130,140,150"></lvc:StackedColumnSeries>
        <lvc:LineSeries Name="Line1" PointGeometry="{x:Null}" Values="20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,100,220,240,260,280,300" Stroke="#fc174c" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="3" ></lvc:LineSeries>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

I tried specifying transparency, but it had no effect. Is there any other way?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: In the image, I want the gray line on the y-axis to come out of the column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The text content has been modified by adding code.